# Unable to open notification from wearable emulator to phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os, android-wear-notification

MobileActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
//import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
//import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;


import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MobileActivity extends Activity {

    private NotificationCompat.Builder notification_builder;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notification_manager;
    Button button1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile);}



    public void showNotification (View v){



        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark);
        builder.setContentText("This took lot of effort");
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        Intent intent = new Intent (this,NotificationActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager NM =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NM.notify(0, builder.build());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mobile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

NotificationActivity.java

```
package com.example.kaushikshanmugam.lab07_6312;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);


        Button edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationActivity.this, MobileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my mobile activity and notification activity code. The notification is popped on the wear emulator but the app crashes when trying to open from the wear to the phone.

Comment: And what is the stacktrace associated with the crash?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SCNotifListActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//action for google wear
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.sc_app_icon,getString(R.string.app_name), resultPendingIntent);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message).setNumber(count).setAutoCancel(true)
                .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action));
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```